# How do I inject services into a Grails 3 command?

Tags: angularjs, grails, grails-plugin, grails-services, grails-3.3

In a Grails 3 app, how do I create a CLI command that leverages the app's Service and Domain classes?

> The following ***did not work***:

1. `grails create-app test-grails3-angular-cmd --profile=angular`
2. `cd server`
3. `grails create-command MyExample`
4. Implement MyExample:

   ```
   package test.grails3.angular.cmd

   import grails.dev.commands.*

   class MyExampleCommand implements GrailsApplicationCommand {
       def testService

       boolean handle() {
           testService.test()
           return true
       }
   }
   ```
5. `grails create-service TestService`
6. Implement TestService:

   ```
   package test.grails3.angular.cmd

   import grails.transaction.Transactional

   @Transactional
   class TestService {

       def test() {
           System.out.println("Hello, test service!")
       }
   }
   ```

   7. `grails run-command my-example`

> Command execution error: Cannot invoke method test() on null object

How can I fix this?

I am using grails 3.3.0.M2.

Comment: I don't have a place to test this, so just putting it as a comment so you can test it quickly (instead of an answer).  Does this work for you?  Holders.applicationContext.testService.whateverMethod()

Comment: what does this have to do with angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyExampleCommand` is not a bean, I believe, where service can be injected. However, `applicationContext` is available in `GrailsApplicationCommand` (extends `ApplicationCommand` trait) which can be leveraged directly to get the service bean.

```
class MyExampleCommand implements GrailsApplicationCommand {

    boolean handle() {
        TestService testService = applicationContext.getBean(TestService)
        testService.test()
        return true
    }
}
```